# Bottom align columns in bootstrap-ui

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angular and bootstrap-ui.  I have two columns beside each other, the right one has a larger height then the the left due to the presence of controls.  All I want to do is add some text in the right column that is aligned with the bottom of the left column, which should be easy.  I will not admit how long I struggled with it.

It looks like the problem is that the left column itself is top aligned.  so I have something like this:

```
*****************
*      * *       * 
* col 1* * col 2 *
******** *       *
         *       *
         *********
```

I would like to cause col 1 to align with the bottom of col 2 within the row.  From there aligning text in col 1 with the bottom of the col should be easy.

I've found many supposed solutions, but they don't seem to work.  The most common involve overriding the display and vertical-align properties of the CSS, but doing this seems to screw up the rows alignment in odd ways.  I've seen col 1 end up after col 2 or the row shrinking to not use it's full width of the page.  The point being my attempts to override elements are messing with bootstrap.  I believe this is because most suggestions are not actually for angular and bootstrap-ui.

The closest I got to something working was setting display:fluid for the row.  This got the columns to be the same size without interfering with the rest of the look and feel.  However, I then couldn't use text-right or verticle-align to position the text within col 1 on the bottom right of the column.

How can I get my text in my first column to align with the bottom of col 2?

Comment: Show some HTML, please.

Comment: If the content is fixed, the shortest route would be to set heights on each col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are issues that you can have if you try to use vertical-align within a bootstrap container. Even if you also try use (parent) `display:table;` and then in (child) with `display:table-cell;`. You lose the height control.

Your best option here is probably as I have set up in this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/cL3c65ac/5/embedded/result/)**.

But saying that... because we use margin-top and when you resize the window to a smaller screen size you still have the problem with the top margin as you will see in the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/cL3c65ac/5/embedded/result/).

But you can control this by using Bootstrap's `lg, md, sm and xs` to keep your text lined up, again this is also set up in the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/cL3c65ac/5/embedded/result/) to show how you can control this problem.

Resize the window, I have the large view setup in the fiddle.

```
<html !DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" >    
<style>
.block{
overflow: visible;
} 
.block-a {
margin-top:200px;
height:100px; 
}
.block-b {
height:300px; 
padding-top:200px;
overflow: visible;
}       
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container col-lg-12"><br></div>
<div class="container col-lg-12 bg-warning block">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 bg-primary block-a "> Hello</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 bg-info block-b ">Great, lined up to  the left.</div>
</div>

<div class="container col-lg-12"><br></div>
<div class="container col-lg-12 bg-success block">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3 col-  sm-offset-2 col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1 bg-primary block-a "> Hello</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-5 col-   sm-offset-2 col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-1 bg-info block-b ">Great, lined up to the    left.</div>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does work, though I would really prefer something that wasn't so...hard coded.  Does boostrap really not have a simple class that can be applied to your column and/or row to tell it how to do alignment of columns automatically?

Comment: Bootstrap is just the same code that we already have, it is just put together to do certain thing collectively you could say. And works largely to be responsive  by using percentages etc. Which ever way you spin it you have to think about ... how is it going to work on All Devices. You can see when you resize the window how things can jump to different levels. This is your main issue. Bootstrap can help you control this problem.